# Select last record of each table on database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to show the last record of each *table* from my *database*. All tables have the same structure like the ones below:

```
+------+-----------+------------+--------+-----------+
|  id  |   kh_ho   |   kh_ha    | total  | base_num  |
+------+-----------+------------+--------+-----------+
| 1    |   2400    |     2000   | 2569   | 12548     |
| 2    |   2600    |     2195   | 2569   | 12548     |
| 3    |   2800    |     2400   | 2569   | 12548     |
| 4    |   4700    |     4450   | 2569   | 12548     |
| 5    |   5200    |     5000   | 2569   | 12548     |
| 6    |   4800    |     4795   | 2569   | 12548     |
| 7    |   5000    |     4990   | 2569   | 12548     |
| 8    |   5800    |     5795   | 2569   | 12548     |
| 9    |   7500    |     7950   | 2569   | 12548     |
| 10   |   8300    |     8495   | 2569   | 12548     |
```

I wanted to show the last record of each *database table* and echo `kh_ho` and `kh_ha` on the last two column in a table.

Can you help me on this by using ***PHP*** and ***MySQL***?

Comment: what did you tried so far?

Comment: Is `id` an auto incremented primary key??

Comment: yes id is incremened primary key . 
i try for "   $sql='SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ("kh_ho")
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA="mydb";';
" and no result

Comment: well, that's not too hard?

Comment: looks like xy problem, why do you need to do this?

Comment: no ... i want show some last record of each table just ...

Comment: usually there is no sense in displaying any (right, any - there is no last row, there can be row with max id or max date) row from all tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the last record will have highest id ,

```
 SELECT * FROM `yourtable` WHERE `id` = (select max(id) from  `yourtable`);
```

Use can use order by clause also

```
SELECT * FROM `yourtable` ORDER BY id  DESC LIMIT 1;
```

For getting all table entry

```
SELECT * FROM `firsttable` WHERE `id` = (select max(id) from  `firsttable`)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `secondtable` WHERE `id` = (select max(id) from  `secondtable`) 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `thirdtable` WHERE `id` = (select max(id) from  `thirdtable`)
.
.
.
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `lasttable` WHERE `id` = (select max(id) from  `lasttable`);
```

Union all Will ensure that same entry are listed for different table

Edit2

```
<?php

  $sql = 'show tables';
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $numofrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    $sqlQuery = '';
    $i=0;
    while($d = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $i++;

        if($i==$numofrows){
          $sqlQuery .= "SELECT * FROM `".$d[0]."` WHERE `id` = (select max(id) from  `".$d[0]."`)" ;
        }else{
          $sqlQuery .= "SELECT * FROM `".$d[0]."` WHERE `id` = (select max(id) from  `".$d[0]."`) UNION ALL " ;
        }
    }

    echo $sqlQuery; //your Sql Query

?>
```

Comment: how i use it fro all of table in my database ? i can't write table name for each table ...

Comment: tables are about 95 how i can get name of each table auto and do this code ?

Comment: best way would be get the name in a array in php, and then create the above query , execute it and get the result

Comment: the problem is how get names of all tables ... i use below code for thaht '  $sql="SHOW TABLES;";
  $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  print_r($result);
  foreach($result AS $k=>$v)
  {
   echo $v['tablename'];

  }'

Answer (score 6):

how about using this single line query?

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY id  DESC LIMIT 1;
```

**Full PHP Code:**

Well, I'm not a PHP guy but this should help:

```
    <?php
        $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost','test','test','test') or die('Error connecting to MySql Server.');
        $queryShowTable = "SHOW TABLES;";
        $querySelect_Template = "SELECT kh_ho, kh_ha FROM ";
        $listOftables = mysqli_query($dbc,$queryShowTable) or die('Error querying database.');
        echo '<table>';
        while($table=mysqli_fetch_array($listOftables)){
            $querySelectData = $querySelect_Template.$table[0].' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;';          
            $tableData = mysqli_query($dbc,$querySelectData) or die('Error querying database.');
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tableData)){
                echo '<tr><td>'.$row[0].'</td><td>'.$row[1].'</tr>';
            }                
        }
        echo '</table>';
        mysqli_close($dbc);            
    ?>
```

Comment: is mytable contain all of table in data base ?

Comment: nope it's a single table... replace "MyTable" with your table name. You need to iterate for each table and execute the query.

Comment: how i can get name of each table (they are bout 95 tables)? and use this ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to fire one query:

```
SHOW TABLES;
```

In result you will get all tables.
Now using foreach() of PHP

```
foreach($resultset AS $k=>$v)
{
  // fire query over here:
  //i.e. SELECT * FROM `$v['tablename']` ORDER BY id  DESC LIMIT 1;
}
```

It is just an idea.

Comment: i do that an in foreach i wrtie echo $v[tablename'} an nothing shows 
can i run show tables with mysqli($con,$sql) ? beacuse when i call that ... and print_r the ans ... it shows  [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 98 [type] => 0 and cant use it foreach

Comment: USE $V['Tables_in_write_your_db_name'] instead of $v['tablename'].
replace write_your_db_name with your actual db name.